# Display popover over a editable textbox to pick the items in the popover

Tags: javascript, html, popover

I need a popover where it can popup and show the list, when one of the items are clicked it would populate on the textbox without clearing the previouly typed or pouplated content.

[image]

**Here the textbox has other_text which means the textbox can be typed in addition to picked tag lists from the popover.**

The items are preferred to be loaded from js array after the textbox is loaded to the html document.

I have tried with

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Click anywhere in the document to close this popover" />
```

Comment: I would suggest that this isn't the right use case for a popover library. I'd suggest you use a tag list control instead, something like this: https://select2.org/tagging

Comment: Its not just the tagging, it should allow text in between too. Sorry let me revise the example image.